# Streaming music from iPod Touch to Nexus 5

Tags: android, ios

I would like to stream music from my iPod Touch to my Nexus 5. I know a few ways to do it over WiFi but I look for a way to do this when I don't have access to WiFi. Is there a way to do this over Bluetooth or by using my Nexus 5 as a hotspot?

Comment: A good starting point would be to look into using the Nexus as an AirPlay device. I haven't looked, and thus it's not worthy of an answer, but that's where I would start.

Comment: I did found a software that makes an android device to appear like an Airplay device. The thing is that it works only on WiFi and i look for an alternative.